# Python: Creating a file list from a directory of .txt files

Tags: python, glob

I'm trying to load a corpus from a directory of .txt files then create a document list.

I thought it would be simple enough, but when I run it nothing happens, am I missing something?

```
import os.path
import re
import glob

 def load_data_from_dir(path):
file_list = glob.glob('/transcripts/*.txt')


# create document list:
documents_list = []
for filename in file_list:
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        text = f.read()
        f.close()
        documents_list.append(text)
print("Total Number of Documents:",len(documents_list))
return documents_list
```

Comment: you are definitely missing that in Python indentation matters - fix that first

Comment: For starters: you miss the corrent indentation of your `def load_data_from_dir` function. Do you get any errors?  Please add the stacktrace / error message if so and [edit] the code to fix the indentation. f.close() is not needed when using context handler `with` for open. Thanks

Comment: It is not likely that `/transcripts` is at the lowest level of your filesystem, so you need a `.` in there so it's relative to the cwd: `file_list = glob.glob('./transcripts/*.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to indent your code in python properly.
Also, check the path of the code. Either give a absolute path or a relative path. Absolute path would work perfectly though.

```
import os.path
import re
import glob

def load_data_from_dir():
    file_list = glob.glob('./transcripts/*.txt')


    # create document list:
    documents_list = []
    for filename in file_list:
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            text = f.read()
            documents_list.append(text)
    print("Total Number of Documents:",len(documents_list))
    return documents_list

load_data_from_dir()
```

Comment: f.close not needed together with 'with' statement

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

1. The function (`load_data_from_dir`) body is not indented. Indent all the lines (upto your return statement) in the function body
2. File opened with `with` construct should not be closed explicitly. Remove `f.close()`
3. If this is a single module and you run only a function. Then nothing will happen. You need to make sure you call that function. So add

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       load_data_from_dir(...)
   ```